# Info.plist file for react native ios app using expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using expo and I want to add facebook app id to info.plist !
How I expose the entire info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

Valid question, but the thing is in expo , you dont have access to Info.plist , if you develop in Pure react native you have the access. So in case of expo , you should add your facebook app ID inside the app.json file in your project ,

Like this:

> iOS standalone app Add your app's Bundle ID as a Bundle ID in the app
>   settings page pictured above. If you still have the host.exp.Exponent
>   ID listed there, remove it. In your app.json, add a field
>   facebookScheme with your Facebook login redirect URL scheme found here
>   under 4. Configure Your info.plist. It should look like "fb123456".
>   Also in your app.json, add your Facebook App ID and Facebook Display
>   Name under the facebookAppId and facebookDisplayName keys.

Check the link :
[expo-facebook](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/)